# Return ComboBox From Function?

Tags: c#

The below code has a list and loops through each string item in that list and adds it to a ComboBox.  This functions correctly, but I am curious if there is a possible way to pass a string list and ComboBox into a function and return the ComboBox with each item in the string list being added.

Example: gets a string list, then adds each string item to the list.  This is great if there's one ComboBox; but if there are 3 or more, to avoid code repetition, passing in a list and ComboBox would save code.

```
List<string> myList = getList();

foreach (string listItem in myList)
{
     myComboBox.Items.Add(listItem);
}
```

Comment: `myComboBox.Items.AddRange(myList.ToArray());`

Comment: Its funny you have posted this, you've basically answered the question in your post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can make method like

```
private void FillCombo(ComboBox myComboBox, List<string> list);
{
    foreach (string listItem in myList)
    {
         myComboBox.Items.Add(listItem);
    }
    //alternatively, you can add it like fubo suggested in comment
    //myComboBox.Items.AddRange(myList.ToArray());
}
```

and call it from somewhere in code

```
List<string> myList = getList();
FillCombo(this.comboBox1, myList);
FillCombo(this.comboBox2, myList);
// etc...
```

Comment: It isn't a big deal, but as SO suggests, It would be nice to leave a comment why she/he downvoted and where is the problem or mistake in an answer.